# Wrap JSON object or change JSON format

Tags: json

### ## I'm new to Javascript and JSON. I need to convert an array of data like this:

{
    "Name":"University of Minnesota Extension",
    "datetime":"1914-00-00T00:00:00",
    "Latitude":44.982515,
    "Longitude":-93.17489,
    "size":2
  }

### ## to this:

{
      "geometry" : {
         "type":"Point",
         "coordinates": [
             44.982515,
             -93.17489
                        ]
             },
       "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "size": 2,
                "datetime": "1914-00-00T00:00:00"
              }
      }

I have completely no idea how to transfer the format for my data, please help!

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
records = `your original list`
newrecords = []


for (var i=0; i<records.length;i++)
{ 
    var newrecord = {
    "geometry" : {
    "type":"Point",
      "coordinates": [records[i].Latitude,records[i].Longitude] 
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "size": records[i].size,
      "datetime": records[i].datetime
    } 
  }

  newrecords.push(newrecord)
```

}

Comment: Hi this may seem dumb, how do I run a JS file from terminal?

Comment: You could try using node.js for example. But if your intent is to try some stuff out, you might want to look at jsfiddle.net. That's  a great site for messing around with javascript code.